# VBA Excel run macro with IF AND THEN statement in sheet with ListObjects

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, calculated-columns, listobject

I'm trying to run a macro with an IF AND THEN statement in a sheet with ListObjects.

[image]

In sheet "CommissionVoice" the macro has to check IF column "L" contains the text values "No Pay" or "Below Target". If it contains these strings then column K (an integer) needs to be calculated with column E (a percentage).

So far I was only able to create the next (Test) code with a simple IF statement but that didn't work:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CommissionVoice")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(12).DataBodyRange
    
    For Each cel In rng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "No pay") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = "OK"
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is `"CommissionVoice"` the sheet name, as you say in words, is it the table name, as you use in the shown code, or both and your code runs on the active sheet? Is the first table column A:A? Then, the respective column where you try searching looks to be filtered. Do you want iterating between the visible cells or between all cells, even hidden?

Comment: Code works for me. What didn't work for you? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Why don't you use a formula in another column. It's rarely a good idea to overwrite cell values.

Comment: @Rory the sheet is full with other formula's which conflict when I want to use one in column K

Comment: @ShaiRado it didn't work for me, it keeps throwing a "Run-Time error '13' - Type Mismatch " on code line: If InStr(1, cel.Value, "No pay") > 0 Then

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, the table name is exactly _CommissionVoice_ and it's selectable with `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CommissionVoice").Range.Select`. First column is A:A but the sheet is not filtered, hence I ran a short test and I still receive the same error. I don't think I need to iterate ...

Comment: If you get a type mismatch, then something is stored in the cell that cannot be used as parameter into `InStr` - likely an error (maybe  #N/A?).

Comment: The sign on the bottom right header looks to say that it is filtered. But not so important. The code should work if no error exists in the invoked `cel`. When stopped on error, moving the cursor over `cel.value`, what does it display?

Comment: @FunThomas I checked, you're right, any idea how I can wrap an IF ERROR around this?

Comment: @FaneDuru I filtered for the sake of the image :) hovering over `cel.value' shows an _ERROR 2015_

Comment: So, it is an error in that cell. You can escape it using `If Not IsError ...` or using `Debug.Print cel.address` to see which is the problematic cell...

Answer (score 1):

Type mismatch errors can have different causes, for example you cannot assign a string to a number or a number to an object. Usually this error is easy to find using the debugger. Check all involved values/variables of the statement that raises the error.

In this specific case, the command `InStr(1, cel.Value, "No pay")` is raising the error. The only value that could be of wrong type is `cel.Value` which represents the value of an actual cell. Now a cell can hold only a numeric value, a string value, a boolean value or an error. Errors are not strings, they are a separate data type. When you see `#N/A`, this is not the String `"#N/A"`. Those error values cannot be used as and not be converted into any other data type, and therefore you get the type mismatch error.

You can check for errors in VBA with the function `IsError`. So one could think that the statement should simply be changed into

```
If Not IsError(cel.Value) And InStr(1, cel.Value, "No pay") > 0 Then
```

however, that will not solve the issue - VBA will always check all parts of the condition and therefore the `InStr`-command would be executed anyhow.

2 attempts (there are other)

```
' 2 separate If-statements
If Not IsError(cel.Value) Then
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "No pay") > 0 Then
        (...)
    End If
End If

' Store the value into an intermediate variable and change an error to blank
Dim cellValue as Variant
cellValue = cel.Value
If IsError(cellValue) Then cellValue = ""
If InStr(1, cellValue, "No pay") > 0 Then
    (...)
End If
```

But as already stated in the comments, it is likely it is better to solve this with a formula.

Comment: 2 more questions if possible; how can I add (OR) another string to search on in the range on line : "If InStr(1, cel.Value, "No pay", OR "Below Target") > 0 Then" And how can I multiply 2 columns in the line: "cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = [Adjustment] * [NPS]"? do I need to set another range?

Answer (score 1):

### In an Excel Table (`ListObject`)

[image]

```vb
Sub Test()

    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("CommissionVoice")
    
    With lo
        
        ' Get the column indexes.
        Dim colAdj As Long: colAdj = lo.ListColumns("Adjustments").Index
        Dim colNps As Long: colNps = lo.ListColumns("NPS").Index
        Dim colPer As Long: colPer = lo.ListColumns("NPS Performance").Index
        
        With .DataBodyRange ' excluding headers
            
            ' Write the values from the data columns to arrays.
            Dim adjData() As Variant: adjData = .Columns(colAdj).Value
            Dim npsData() As Variant: npsData = .Columns(colNps).Value
            Dim perData() As Variant: perData = .Columns(colPer).Value
            
            Dim r As Long
            
            ' Loop over the rows and modify the values in the arrays.
            For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
                Select Case CStr(perData(r, 1))
                    Case "No pay", "Below Target"
                        ' Maybe some rounding 'nps = Round(nps*(1-adj),2)' ?
                        npsData(r, 1) = npsData(r, 1) * (1 - adjData(r, 1))
                        perData(r, 1) = "OK"
                    'Case Else ' do nothing
                End Select
            Next
            
            ' Write the arrays back to their data columns.
            .Columns(colNps).Value = npsData
            .Columns(colPer).Value = perData
        
        End With
    
    End With

    ' Inform (don't know the jargon).
    MsgBox "Negative commissions applied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, on the 2nd line : Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("renamedtoactivesheet") I get an <subscript out of range> error. Do you know what that can be?

Comment: Just `Set ws = ActiveSheet`. You don't need the `wb` variable then.

Comment: one question: how can I make the percentage in colAdj increase the value in colNps instead of decreasing it as it calculates now ?

Comment: maybe someone else has an idea about this?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about you. Just change the `1 - adjData(r, 1)` to `1 + adjData(r, 1)`.